# React Native: Sticky section headers in ListView are not sticky

Tags: react-native

The documentation for renderSectionHeader in ListView [used to say](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.33/docs/listview.html#rendersectionheader) "If provided, a sticky header is rendered for this section. The sticky behavior means that it will scroll with the content at the top of the section until it reaches the top of the screen, at which point it will stick to the top until it is pushed off the screen by the next section header."

However, that has been removed and it [now just says](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#rendersectionheader) "If provided, a header is rendered for this section."

They have added two props [stickyHeaderIndices](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#stickyheaderindices) and [stickySectionHeadersEnabled](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#stickysectionheadersenabled). I implimented them as follows:

```
<ListView
         style={styles.container}
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} />}
         renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
         renderSectionHeader={(sectionData) => <SectionHeader {...sectionData} />}
         stickySectionHeadersEnabled = {true}
         stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
       />
```

However, on the iOS simulator my headers are not sticky. I have not tried to run it on a device.

Comment: Is your <ListView /> inside of a navigator by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

There might be three reason for this :-

1) I am assuming you are cloning data with rows and sections if not then do that like this:

```
this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(this.state.data)
})
```

2) The first reason is you are using listView inside scrollview..

3)You don't have to give `stickySectionHeadersEnabled = {true}` for iOS . please remove and try again.

4) If you are using react-native version `0.42-0.43` then upgrade it to 0.44 and it would resolve the issue. (mostly for android)

5) Let's check the code.

Cheers :)

Comment: #1 I am - dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds). #2 - I am not using a ListView inside a ScrollView. #3 - I have tried it with and without stickySectionHeadersEnabled. #4 - I am on  "react-native": "0.43.4". Upgradding to  0.44 did not change things. #5 - Not sure where else to check...

Comment: Full Source: https://www.dropbox.com/s/unv2u9k8s8gp7ag/DirectoryListScreen.js?dl=0

Comment: did you get through it??

Answer (score 0):

If you're ListView is inside of a NavigatorIOS, the section header might disappear behind the translucent navigation bar.

In order to solve this, add translucent={false} to NagigatorIOS:

```
<NavigatorIOS 
  translucent={false}
  ...
/>
```

It's better then setting a paddingTop because the height of the navigation bar can vary based on iPad/iPhone or orientation.

Comment: I am using a StackNavigator from "react-navigation"